# Google sheets conditional formatting to colour cell if the same cell in another sheet is not empty

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, conditional-formatting

I have 2 sheets **A** and **B**. I want **sheet A** to colour cells if the exact same cell in **sheet B** is not empty. For example if cell `A1` in **sheet B** has a string, then cell `A1` in **sheet A** will be coloured.

Let's say I want to do this to compare a large range, how should I go about doing this?

Example: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1P3Ob_mclpXWmILfKwD4R6JN2wAYPUcNZlmtF9LxilV0/edit?usp=sharing

Cells `A2:C2`, `D5` and `K2` in **sheet B** are not empty. So the corresponding cells in **sheet A** will be coloured red.

Comment: See this article: [https://productivityspot.com/conditional-formatting-based-on-another-cell-google-sheets/](https://productivityspot.com/conditional-formatting-based-on-another-cell-google-sheets/)

Comment: @NKSM Nope, that article refers to within sheet cells. What I need is a code to compare to a cell in another sheet.

Comment: And this one: [https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4734-google-sheets-conditional-formatting-based-on-another-sheet.html](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4734-google-sheets-conditional-formatting-based-on-another-sheet.html)

Comment: And another one: [https://support.google.com/docs/thread/4490297?hl=en](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/4490297?hl=en).

Comment: @NKSM thank you, but it still does not solve my problem. The match function does not work with empty cells in sheet A.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the following formula as a **conditional formatting rule**:

```
=NOT(ISBLANK(INDIRECT("B!"&address(row(),column()))))
```

*(the formula in `A!A2` is there to **just show** you what happens in sheet `B`)*

[image]

Comment: thank you so much, it works. However I realized in my original document, the cells are merged. Example: docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/… So in sheet B, cells A2:D2 are merged, but sheets only takes cell A2 as filled so in sheet A, only cell A2 is colored. How can I make it so that it recognises merged cells as filled?

Comment: *"thank you so much, it works. However... How can I make it so that it recognises merged cells as filled?"* I don't think you can achieve it using merged cells. Not even with a script. In any case, since your original question is answered you should re-accept the answer. As you can see from the upvotes it is very useful for others. As for the merged cells -since it would require a completely different solution as also pointed out  by Marios- you should post a new question referencing this one as well.

Answer (score 1):

### Explanation:

Not familiar how this could be done with a custom conditional formatting formula so wait for other guys to help you out with that.

However, I can offer you a Google Apps Script solution.

The following script will check for the data range in `sheet B` and it will construct a color array. An element of this array will have the white hex color `#ffffff"` if the value in the `values` array is empty, or a red color `#ff0000` if the value is not blank.

Then it will color `sheet A` based on this color array in one go. The script is relatively fast even for large ranges.

### Solution / Workaround:

Don't forget to adjust `"sheet A"` and `"sheet B"` to the name of your sheets.

```
function colorCells(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sheetToColor = ss.getSheetByName("sheet A");
  const sheetToCheck = ss.getSheetByName("sheet B");  
  const bValues = sheetToCheck.getDataRange().getValues();
  const aColors=bValues.map(r=>r.map(v=>v==''?"#ffffff":"#ff0000"));
  sheetToColor.getRange(1,1,sheetToCheck.getLastRow(),sheetToCheck.getLastColumn()).
  setBackgrounds(aColors);
}
```

### How to use that:

Click on `Tools` => `Scipt editor`, copy, paste & save the aforementioned code and then execute it by clicking on the play button.

If you want this to work "automatically" then you can set up a time trigger to execute this function for you every `n` minutes.

---

### Bonus code:

You can do the same operation but on a more user-interactive way. Again, copy, paste & save the following script to the script editor but this time **don't execute it** as it can work by itself.

The following script will change the color of a cell in `sheet A` upon **user** edits on the same cell in `sheet B`:

```
function onEdit(e) {  
  // adjust this to your needs:
  const sheetToColorName = "sheet A";
  const sheetToCheckName = "sheet B";
  const rng = e.range;
  const cell = rng.getA1Notation();      
  if (rng.getSheet().getName()==sheetToCheckName){
    const sheetToColor = e.source.getSheetByName(sheetToColorName);
    if(rng.getValue()!=''){        
        sheetToColor.getRange(cell).setBackground("#ff0000"); //red     
    }
    else {
        sheetToColor.getRange(cell).setBackground("#ffffff"); //white
    }    
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! But it returns an error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRange' of null"

Comment: @Portato like I said in the explanation of my answer. Make sure your sheets have exactly the names `sheet A` and `sheet B`. No extra spaces, no different upper or lower case letters. Has to be exactly like that. As you can see the name has a space in between. But anyway, it you are using merged cells then this solution is not going to work I think but you can try.