# Currency Conditional formatting in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I am looking to automatically format my cells in a way that when the amount of a cell is already at more than 50,000 it automatically converts to IDR currency but if it's below that amount, it would be on $ currency. Please help

Answer (score 2):

Please try the following formula

```
=INDEX(IF(LEN(B2:B),
     IF(B2:B>=50000,TEXT(B2:B*GOOGLEFINANCE("Currency:USDIDR"),"Rp0.00"),TEXT(B2:B,"$0.00")),""))
```

[image]

Functions used:

- [`INDEX`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242)
- [`IF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364)
- [`LEN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094081)
- [`TEXT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094139)
- [`GOOGLEFINANCE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281)

Comment: This worked but, I forgot that I can't put a formula on the formula bar cause the file is only imported (used IMPORTRANGE) and if I put a formula the whole data would be gone. Is there any way this can be achieved using conditional formatting?

Comment: *"Is there any way this can be achieved using conditional formatting?"* [Conditional Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65592986/google-sheets-conditional-formatting-to-colour-cell-if-the-same-cell-in-another/65594433#65594433) is a completely different thing. Now if you used the importrange I suggest you use an additional column/sheet dedicated to just this formula. If still in trouble, please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.